Python plot errorbands for xerr and yerr combined
I have x and y data as lists. For each one, I have two data sets representing the lower and upper end of an error band that I want to plot.
I am using plt.fill_between and plt.fill_betweenx to plot the error bands.
My problem is that it is not a combined error band and that overlapping errorbands look weird in a plot.
How can I plot a combined error band, accounting for both x and y errors (and the combination of the two) as ONE band?
Please find below an example code generated by ChatGPT to reproduce my problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate x data from -30 to 30 in steps of 1 as a list
x = list(range(-30, 31))

# Generate random y data between 1 and 10
np.random.seed(0)  # For reproducibility
y = np.random.uniform(1, 10, len(x)).tolist()

# Create x_lower_band and x_upper_band
x_lower_band = [xi - 1 for xi in x]
x_upper_band = [xi + 1 for xi in x]

# Create y_lower_band and y_upper_band
y_lower_band = [yi * 0.98 for yi in y]
y_upper_band = [yi * 1.02 for yi in y]

# Create a plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

# Plot the original y data
plt.plot(x, y, label='Random Data', color='blue')

# Plot the vertical error band (y-axis uncertainty) using fill_between
plt.fill_between(x, y_lower_band, y_upper_band, color='lightblue', alpha=0.5, label='Y Uncertainty Band')

# Plot the horizontal error band (x-axis uncertainty) using fill_betweenx
plt.fill_betweenx(y, x_lower_band, x_upper_band, color='lightcoral', alpha=0.5, label='X Uncertainty Band')

# Add labels and title
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Random Data with X and Y Uncertainty Bands')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()


It is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could include a sketch of the expected result.
If you have data points with both x and y errors then you could just use plt.errorbar. E.g.
xerr = np.abs(np.vstack([x_lower_band, x_upper_band]) - x)
yerr = np.abs(np.vstack([y_lower_band, y_upper_band]) - y)
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr, xerr, label='Random Data', color='blue',
             linestyle='--', ecolor='black')



Thank you for your help!
I would like to avoid plotting "only" the errorbars at the data points I have.
Instead, I would like to plot an errorband as shown in this example here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html
However, I cant figure out how to combine xerr and yerr in one band.
In my data, xerr and yerr can occur at the same time so the band should include this area as well.

Ok, just to be clear, the example you shared has only yerr and uses fill_between (as in your post) to plot it. I'm not sure how you can combine both xerr and yerr in a meaningful way in one band and how this figure would look like. In regular line plot you have a mapping x -> y, in a plot with yerr band - x -> [y-yerr, y+yerr], in a plot with only errorbars you show that each measurement has some uncertainty. I cannot come up with the explanation for your suggestion. But I'm not an expert :)

In my example I use fill_between and fill_betweenx to plot error bands in y- and x-direction, respectively. However, this only shows the errors individually and does not take into account that an x and a y error can be occur simultaneously. E.g. measurement points (with yerr) taken at different positions (with xerr).
In your plot, you create black + markers as error bars. This means that the actual data point could be anywhere not only on the black lines of the + but anywhere within the 4 quadrants of the + (or anywhere within this square). I want to plot this "square" - but as error band.

Maybe this would be helpful? You could try to vary the errors for x and y separately. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17398/

I actually found that before asking the question here but I will give it another look - maybe I can make it work. Thanks for your help!
